# Windows keeps deleting iconv.dll

Tags: windows-7, boot, dll, mobileme

I'm having a frustrating problem with my Windows 7 setup. When my computer boots, AppleSyncNotifier.exe (which is the MobileMe control panel) complains: "The program can't start because iconv.dll is missing from your computer. try reinstalling the program to fix this problem."

And sure enough, if I try to open the MobileMe control panel, it fails.

So then I run the MobileMe installer, click "Repair," and it reinstalls the files it needs, including (presumably) iconv.dll. Then I can open the MobileMe control panel, it syncs everything like it's supposed to, etc.

Until I boot again. And then iconv.dll is deleted again... so this means I have to do the "Repair" job every time I boot my computer. Grr.

Question: how can I tell what's deleting the iconv.dll file from my system every time I boot? And how can I stop it? :-)

thanks-- E

Comment: What sort of antivirus are you running?  Do you have any jobs which run on shutdown or power on?  Any programs like ccleaner or others which "clean" old files/entries?

Comment: I'm running Microsoft's free "Security Essentials" virus package. It doesn't scan or run at startup or shutdown. I don't have any kind of "cleaner" programs doing anything at startup or shutdown either. :-(

Comment: Though I'd add -- I've found a workaround, which is to download iconv.dll from dll-files.com (which looks shady but seems to be okay), and then I'm putting a copy of it into the directory where the MobileMe control panel seems to be looking for it: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Apple\Mobile Device Support

Answer (score 1):

I've seen poorly-written installation software that adds cleanup tasks (such as deleting files) to the boot process and then never removes them.  I don't have Windows 7, but in Windows XP I would fire up REGEDIT and look in the following places for suspicious items:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnceEx
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce

There are easier ways of toggling these startup items on and off in Windows XP, such as MSCONFIG, but I don't know if that program is still around in Windows 7.

Comment: I didn't find anything at any of those places (except hinky old eFax messenger trying to start itself at boot-- um, I DON'T think so). Thanks for the idea though.